# Add and remove the class based on scroll on multiple divs witht the same class

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll

I have a css animation with the class .fadeIn and I have multiple divs with the class animation where I want to add this class when it comes in to view port and remove the class when it goes out of it. I tried the below code it removes the class but does not add the class when it comes in to view port.

```
function reveal() {
console.log('scoll');
var reveals = document.querySelectorAll(".animation");
for (var i = 0; i < reveals.length; i++) {
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var elementTop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
  console.log();
  
  var elementVisible = 150;
  if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
    reveals[i].classList.add("fadeIn");
      
  } else {
    reveals[i].classList.remove("fadeIn");
      
  }
}
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", reveal);
```